# Move semantics and copy constructor

Tags: c++, c++11, copy-constructor, move-semantics

I wrote a program as below:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class A {
public:
    A() {
    }
    A(A &a) {
        id = a.id;
        cout << "copy constructor" << endl;
    }
    A& operator=(A &other) {
        id = other.id;
        cout << "copy assignment" << endl;
        return *this;
    }
    A(A &&other) {
        id = other.id;
        cout << "move constructor" << endl;
    }
    A& operator=(A &&other) {
        id = other.id;
        cout << "move assignment" << endl;
        return *this;
    }
public:
    int id = 10;
};

A foo() {
    A a;
    return a;
}

int main()
{
    A a;
    A a2(a); // output: copy constructor
    A a3 = a2; // output: copy constructor
    a3 = a2; // output: copy assignment
    A a4 = foo(); // output: 
    a4 = foo(); // output: move assignment
    return 0;
}
```

I compiled it on my Mac OS. The output is:

```
copy constructor
copy constructor
copy assignment
move assignment
```

My question are:

1. Why the output of `A a4 = foo();` is empty? I thought it should call the move constructor.
2. Why the output of `A a3 = a2;` is `copy constructor` instead of `copy assignment`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Because copies and moves may be elided by the compiler if it wishes. The relevant constructor must still exist, but it is explicitly stated in the standard that they might not be invoked. (This is a rare example of a standard-defined optimisation, in particular allowing Return Value Optimisation to be standard-defined also.)
2. Because the use of `=` in initialisation performs construction, not assignment. It's somewhat confusing that this is the syntax. `A a3(a2)`, which is [essentially] equivalent, would be clearer in this regard.

Comment: Thanks your reply. But as for the first point, I am bit confused. If the move constructor might not be invoked, then how could we correctly initialize the l-value as expected? For example, if I rewrite the move constructor as `id = other.id * 10;`, if it's been elided, how could be get the correct id for a4?

Comment: @injoy: Well, that's not how a move constructor is supposed to be written.

Comment: Yes, you're correct. BTW, I added one line `cout << "default constructor" << endl;` in the `A(){}`. And now the output of `A a4 = foo();` is two `default constructor`s. Looks like that `move constructor` is not been called. Why?

Comment: Because, as I said, it does not need to be. The temporary can be used to construct the named object directly, with the potential copy/move elided.

Comment: Then how can we force the compiler to call the move constructor? Because sometimes, if there's a pointer in the class, the move constructor would be much more efficient.

Comment: Not calling either the copy ctor or the move ctor is not as efficient as their being elided. Don't "force" the compiler to do anything: it knows what it's doing.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler is generating default methods for:

```
A (const A &);
A & operator = (const A &);
```

If you add the `const` qualifier to your copy ctor / assign methods, you may see the results you expect.