# Move semantics and constructors when dereferencing a new

Tags: c++11, move-semantics

I have the following code (http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a0e5ff6ee73634ee):

```
#include <iostream    

class A {
  public:
  explicit A(int a)         {std::cout << "Main constructor" << std::endl;}
  A(const A& a)             {std::cout << "Copy constructor" << std::endl;}
  A& operator =(const A& a) {std::cout << "Copy assignment" << std::endl; return *this;}
  A(A&& a)                  {std::cout << "Move constructor" << std::endl;}
  A& operator =(A&& a)      {std::cout << "Move assignemnt" << std::endl; return *this;}
};

int main(void) {
    std::cout << "\nA a3(A(0))" << std::endl;
    A a3(A(0));
    std::cout << "\nA a31(std::move(A(0)))" << std::endl;
    A a31(std::move(A(0)));
    std::cout << "\nA a4(*(new A(0)))" << std::endl;
    A a4(*(new A(0)));
    std::cout << "\nA a41(std::move(*(new A(0))))" << std::endl;
    A a41(std::move(*(new A(0))));
}
```

This code writes the following:

```
A a3(A(0))
Main constructor
```

-> After having read [Move semantics and copy constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19613637/move-semantics-and-copy-constructor) I assume RVO happened and a3 takes over the content of the construction of A(0).

```
A a31(std::move(A(0)))
Main constructor
Move constructor
```

-> OK

```
A a4(*(new A(0)))
Main constructor
Copy constructor
```

-> Why is not this a move constructor instead of the Copy constructor ?

```
A a41(std::move(*(new A(0))))
Main constructor
Move constructor
```

-> OK
EDIT:
After analyzing the problem a little deeper I realized that actually @sameerkn is right. However as @Angew suggested I tried to analyze what is happening with a static variable: such variables are not moved as one could expect (they seem to be treated as const variables).
See here full code:
http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/RCntHB9dcefv93ID

Following code:

```
A a1(testStatic(1));
A a2(std::move(*(a1.getPointer())));  <-- Moving a dereference
std::cout << "\na1.mValue = " << a1.mValue << std::endl;
std::cout << "a2.mValue = " << a2.mValue << std::endl;
```

Will return:

```
Main constructor: This is my long String that should not be SSOed [STATIC]
Copy constructor: This is my long String that should not be SSOed [STATIC]
return aLocal
Move constructor  <-- The dereferenced pointer is moved as expected
Destructor: [mValue moved away]   <-- See here that the string was moved away
Move constructor  <-- Moved again because of std::move
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
new A(0);
```

Creating an object via "new". (NOTE: Its creating a pure object which has an identity which can be identified by the address returned by "new" in code and this object is available to rest to the code for its utilization and in no sense a temporary nameless object.)

And move semantic work on purely temporary object whose identity is not available for utilization.

Comment: Hi @sameerkn, thanks for your comment. Actually new returns a raw pointer and such a pointer is a POD type (http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/PODType) and thus not moveable. In the questions I was wondering why the dereferencing of that pointer was not moved.

Comment: Am think on the terms that: `"Not Movable"` means "Having specific area(address) in address space which is known/identifiable and can be utilized."  "Movable" means "Temporary space/address which is not identifiable during the runtime or temporary objects that cannot be referenced elsewhere in the program". Object created via new are not temporary.

Comment: Hi @sameerkn, thanks for your explanation actually as I wrote in the edit your explanation is the right one.

Answer (score 8):

> ```
> A a4(*(new A(0)))
> Main constructor
> Copy constructor
> ```
>
> -> Why is not this a move constructor instead of the Copy constructor ?

Because dereferencing a pointer gives an lvalue reference. The fact that the pointer itself is an rvalue plays no role—and why should it? You can very easily have an rvalue pointer pointing to something that is most definitely not an rvalue. Example:

```
std::string s{"42"};

std::string* getPointer()
{
  return &s;
}

int main()
{
  std::string x(*getPointer());
  std::cout << s;
}
```

The pointer returned by `getPointer` is an rvalue, just as the pointer returned by `new A`. But you certainly would *not* expect the code to move the contents of `s` into `x`, would you?

Comment: Hi @Angew, I moved the resolution to sameerkn as from the EDIT I wrote it is actually possible to move a dereferenced function however not a new. Your point with static was very interesting. I added a link to a code snippet showing that static variables are actually not moveable (which I had expected but never read).